# SQLiteDatabase SELECT from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to databases and I have three tables

```
PRODUCT_INFO|    FOOD_ADDITIVE_TABLE |      SUPER_TABLE
ID  CODE    |    ID    FOOD_ADDITIVE |      ID  PRODUCT_ID  FOOD_ADDITIVE_ID
1   100     |    1     E621          |      1   1            3
2   156     |    2     E523          |      2   1            2
3   295     |    3     E211          |      3   3            1
```

For example I have code `100` So I need to select `E211` and `E523` from `FOOD_ADDITIVE_TABLE` Because in my `SUPER_TABLE` Product_ID (1) is linked to two food additives (3 and 2).
So here what I did

```
SELECT FOOD_ADDITIVE FROM FOOD_ADDITIVE_TABLE ....And now I need JOIN
```

but problem where? I dont have any additional information in `FOOD_ADDITIVE_TABLE` to join other table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the three tables on the common column and then with a `WHERE` clause you can take only the rows you want:

```
SELECT aa.FOOD_ADDITIVE
FROM FOOD_ADDITIVE_TABLE AS aa
INNER JOIN SUPER_TABLE AS bb
ON aa.ID = bb.FOOD_ADDITIVE_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_INFO AS cc
ON bb.PRODUCT_ID = cc.ID
WHERE cc.CODE = 100;
```

Also have a look [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) about JOIN.